# How rude is it to use " bloody hell " in a conversation?

Tags: expressions

In South Africa throughout the 1960-1980 whilst growing up, ' bloody hell ' was and still is used as an exclamation ( like gee whiz, far out, good Heavens) or as a frustration release ( like damn, oh no! ).
Is it deemed rude to use ' bloody hell ' in conversation?

Comment: It's bloody awful!

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48150/why-is-bloody-hell-offensive-or-shocking

Comment: Expressions like this tend to be very culture-specific, in terms of how "obscene" they are judged to be.  "Hell" aside, the term "bloody" is regarded as quite offensive in some cultures and exceedingly mild in others.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. This site strives to provide well researched, intriguing questions. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good questions. This question could be improved by specifying the sort of conversation you want to use the expression in.

Comment: It's never used in Canada or the US, except by ex-pats. Most people here would recognize it as some sort of British expression of annoyance, probably seeming stronger than it really is.

Comment: I'm just recalling a co-worker's story of visiting somewhere in the UK ca 1970 with a bunch of college buddies.  They figured (from the movies) that in England everyone quite casually used "bloody", so they used the term liberally until someone took them aside and explained that, in the particular part of the country where they were, and with the people they were dealing with, it was considered very rude.  (Of course, things have no doubt changed since 1970.)

Comment: The usual expression is "bloody fucking hell" but in refined company you should modify it to "bloody fucking heck".

Answer (score 1):

In the *Harry Potter* film series, the character of Ron Weasley says 'bloody hell' a lot - it's a kind of catch-phrase in the film franchise.

[For more, click here.](http://www.hexjam.com/uk/entertainment-/the-definitive-ranking-of-ron-weasley-s-bloody-hell-s)

Given that these films are rated PG (Parental Guidance) to 12 (the 12 certificate being given for 'moderate fantasy violence and horror' rather than language), and given that this franchise is a family franchise based on a series of novels which were, at least in the first place, aimed primarily at children, I would say 'bloody hell' is really tame in most parts of the world.

Anecdotally, I doubt I was still getting in trouble for bloody after I was about 10. I can't promise you won't run into anyone who decides to get offended by it, but it's really a child's expletive. Most adults would consider it a tame alternative for an adult expletive like shit. By that I don't mean that only children use it, or that an adult would look childish using it, not at all, it's perfectly common amongst adults. What I mean is a young child might consider it fairly rude and go and tell the teacher, but very few adults are going to consider 'bloody hell' at all rude where I live.

That obviously doesn't mean it's always appropriate, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The  Cambridge Dictionary defines the expression as:

***[Bloody hell](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bloody-hell)*** 
very informal
​
***a rude way of expressing great anger:***

> - *Bloody hell! I've lost my wallet.
>     What the bloody hell did you do that for?*

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how we'd use this expression, but also not in anger: